# Scales name convention

Tags: scales, terminology

Suppose I take the whole step half step pattern from C major scale. Why can't I just impose this pattern to make C# major, D major, D# major, E major, F major ... this way? How to determine if its okey to write D# major or I'm allowed to write Eb major? what are the conventions behind that?

Comment: Please be aware that choosing a preferred answer very soon will deter others from bothering to proffer any of their own. More than half the world isn't even awake yet!

Comment: @Tim thank I didnt realise

Comment: "...write D# major ..." write it where, how? If you wrote a D sharp major key signature on staff, how would you write it? what problem do you see? Something makes me think you haven't tried to write it on staff, or else you would immediately see the practical difference between D sharp major and E flat major.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the key signature matches the tonic note in musical notation. So if you are given sheet music, follow what the sheet music says. If it's written in 7 sharps, you call it C# major/a# minor, not Db major/bb minor.

When you are talking about a piece of music you hear without notation, such as pop music, you do not want to name a key that has double sharps/flats, and most people would also avoid naming keys with 7 sharps/flats. For major keys, this means only naming flat keys, except Gb can be F#, and for minor keys, the keys are a, bb, b, c, c#, d, d#/eb, e, f, f#, g, g#.

Answer (score 8):

Keys with more than 7 sharps or 7 flats in key signature are avoided. For example, D# major would require two double sharps, i.e., (f# c#) g# d# a# e# b# fx cx. It would be quite inconvenient to read. In turn, Eb major has just 3 flats: bb eb ab.

Comment: thank you so much and is this the sole reason?

Comment: im failing to upvote you due to a technical glitch

Comment: @Rajarshi_Rit you probably need more "reputation" points to upvote other answers. Anyway, yes, convenience is the main reason. I could imagine some situation when D# major could be justified, but what normally people do is they switch to the enharmonically equivalent key, as needed.

Comment: thank. its hard to get these scores because I ask seldom and frequently asking not so important question may lead to downvote

Comment: Keys with more than _six_ sharps or flats are avoided.  You can find them, but there is a strong preference for B major over C flat major and for D flat major over C sharp major.

Comment: Aren't there special cases where you might need >6 accidentals e.g. if the music modulates from another key (with ≤6 accidentals), or in a part written for a transposing instrument (when other instruments are written in a key with ≤6 accidentals)? (But yes, you should stick to ≤6 accidentals when there _isn't_ such a reason.)

Comment: @gidds - don't see the point. If a piece is written in, say key C concert, the Bb trumpet part will be written in D to compensate. I reckon there's no need to go to more than 6 sharps or flats at most, in any key signature. And if, say 7 flats were deemed necessary, write in key C!

Comment: @gidds the more common approach is to use the enharmonically equivalent key, so, for example, if the piece is in B major, the B flat instruments will be in D flat major.  There's such a passage, for example, in Copland's Appalachian Spring (the 13-instrument version, which uses only B flat clarinet; the full orchestra version has the clarinets switching between A and B flat instruments).

Comment: @Tim but a key signature of seven flats isn't enharmonically equivalent to C.  It _is_ of course equivalent to B.  This is a great argument against concert pitch scores.  If the concert key signature is 5 or 6 flats, the conductor is going to have to remember that the B flat instrument parts are transposed by a diminished third instead of a major second when discussing the part with the players.

Comment: @gidds I forgot to address the modulation angle.  Similarly, the rule is usually to use the enharmonic equivalent.  If you're going up a major third from A major to C sharp major, you'll typically make it a diminished fourth from A major to D flat major instead.  You can see this sort of thing in 19th century songs, which were published in different keys for different voice types.  Also consider Beethoven's Moonlight Sonata, which is in C sharp minor, but the middle movement, which is in the parallel major key, is in D flat major rather than C sharp major.

Comment: @phoog - yes, I did mean key B. But even so, 5 sharps is probably easier to read than 7 flats, although horns seem to prefer flats - while guitar seem to prefer sharps. Interesting about Moonlight - I'd have thought parallel keys would have been the preference, but fewer 'accidentals' wins, I guess.

Comment: @Tim for a piece in three sharps at concert pitch, would the B flat trumpets and saxes prefer to be in five sharps or seven flats?

Answer (score 6):

That's exactly what we do, to transpose scales into different keys.

The idea of writing down any music is to make it the easiest possible to read. So, we end up with as few sharps or flats as possible in any key, thus key signature.

Key C - none. Key G - 1♯. Key D -2♯, key A - 3♯, key E - 4 ♯, key B - 5♯, key F♯ - 6♯.

And flat keys - key F - 1♭, key B flat - 2♭, key E flat - 3♭, key A flat - 4♭, key D flat - 5♭, key G flat - 6♭.

Note that keys F♯ and G♭ are enharmonic - they are effectively the same set of notes (in 12tet). There is no need to have any more sharps or flats in the key signature - that lot cover all eventualities.

Your D♯ key would require way more - and some double sharps as well (x), so key E♭ (enharmonic), with only 3 flats, does the job  far more simply!

Answer (score 2):

Not too many reasons to write in a nonexistent key of D# actually, unless you are just having an exercise of it for learning purposes. Eb is one of those keys with only one spelling.